# how to add new icon on desktop dynamically in ext.net

Tags: asp.net, desktop, code-behind, ext.net

I am working with Ext.Net 1.5. and I am working with Ext:desktop.

[image]

above screenshot having 2 Icon. now **I want to create new Icon named as Spa dynamically(means from aspx.cs page onLoad).**

I tried through following code but didn't find any solution.

**View desktopIcon dynamically..**

```
            var winspa = new Ext.Net.DesktopWindow
            {
                ID = "WindowFile",
                Title = "File Management",
                Width = Unit.Pixel(870),
                Height = Unit.Pixel(620),
                Icon = Ext.Net.Icon.User,
                Collapsible = true,
                Maximizable = true,
                // Maximized = false,
                Hidden = true
            };

            Ext.Net.DesktopModule dm = new Ext.Net.DesktopModule();
            dm.ModuleID = "spa";
            dm.AutoRun = false ;
            dm.WindowID = "winspa";


            Ext.Net.DesktopShortcut ds = new Ext.Net.DesktopShortcut();
            ds.ModuleID = "spa";
            ds.Text="Spa" ;
            ds.IconCls = "icon-setting";


            winspa.AutoLoad.Url = "settings.aspx";
            winspa.AutoLoad.Mode = Ext.Net.LoadMode.IFrame;
            winspa.Render(this.Form);
```